# Show direction with location anotation

Tags: ios, dictionary, location, mkannotation, directions

I want to show the direction on with the current location annotation, according to the user rotation in iOS map. I manage to calculate the facing angle using below delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
```

but when I tried to add a image to the 'current location annotation' it replace the original user location blue dot (the dot which have animation).
I want to have both. I know that if I use below code that I can have both. But it makes my map rotate as well so that is not I want,

```
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
```

I want to show it like, it is in 'Citymapper'. Like below image (the green arrow with animating blue dot)

[image]

So anyone know how to do this..? 
Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: That might help you :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508296/how-to-rotate-custom-userlocationannotationview-image-using-mapkit-in-swift/39511477#39511477](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508296/how-to-rotate-custom-userlocationannotationview-image-using-mapkit-in-swift/39511477#39511477)