# How to rotate custom userLocationAnnotationView image using MapKit in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview, direction

I'm trying to find a way to show the direction of the user on the map using MapKit.
The native MapKit way to do that always rotate the entire map. 
Since user position is also an MKAnnotationView, I decided to create a specific class to override it and use a specific image (with an arrow).

```
class UserLocationAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override init(annotation: MKAnnotation!, reuseIdentifier: String!) {

    super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    var frame = self.frame
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(130, 130)
    self.frame = frame
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-30, -50)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
*/
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    UIImage(named: "userLocation.png")?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(65, 65, 65, 65))


}
```

Now I'm trying to find a way to rotate that MKAnnotationView image in the didUpdateHeading func of the locationManager.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate { 

var userLocationView :MKAnnotationView?

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    print(newHeading.magneticHeading)
}
```

The print of newHeading.magneticHeading works and it pretty accurate.
Now how can I rotate my custom UserLocationAnnotationView ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't give you complete code examples at this point but I hope I can give you some pointers to go off on.

First, I don't think you would necessarily have to subclass `MKAnnotationView`. You could simply assign your `UIImage` to its [`image`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452094-image) property. I think that would make things easier unless you do require the customization.

Now, I assume you have successfully added the annotation to the map and have a reference to it.

To rotate the heading indicator, I see three options:

1. **Rotate `MKAnnotationView`'s [`image`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452094-image) property**:

   - Method: When the heading changes, create a rotated copy of the `UIImage` and assign it to the `image` property. [Example](https://gist.github.com/ffried/0cbd6366bb9cf6fc0208) (not tested).
   - Con: Can't easily animate the rotation.
2. **Rotate the `MKAnnotationView` itself**:

   - Method: When the heading changes, use `MKAnnotationView`'s/`UIView`'s [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform) property. Assign an appropriate [`CGAffineTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1666405-cgaffinetransform) to it.
   - Pro: Easiest
   - Con: Also rotates the detail/callout views. If you need these, this will not be an option for you.
3. **Put the `UIImage` into a `UIImageView` and [add that one as a subview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview) to `MKAnnotationView`**:

   - Method: Similar to 2.  but use the [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform) property on the `UIImageView` directly not on the `MKAnnotationView` itself. This way callout views are not rotated.
   - Pro: Should work well.
   - Con: A bit more work.

What you also need:

- A function to convert from degrees to radians. The affine transformations require radians.
- If you want to animate the rotation (except for 1.) wrap the change to the `transform` property in `UIView`'s **static** [`animate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate) method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arthur! Even if you didn't gave any code you answer was precise and with your different methods I found my way to make it work. I decided to use the second method as I didn't needed any callout view for the userAnnotationView. Also the last advise about using UIView's animate method was a huge help. Thanks to you again